# Scala Play passing variable to view not working

Tags: scala, playframework

This code works fine:

In the controller:

```
Ok(views.html.payment(message,test,x_card_num,x_exp_date,exp_year,exp_month,x_card_code,x_first_name,x_last_name,x_address,x_city,x_state,x_zip,save_account,product_array,x_amount,products_json,auth_net_customer_profile_id,auth_net_payment_profile_id,customer_id))
```

In the view:

```
@(message: String, test: String, x_card_num: String, x_exp_date: String,exp_year: String, exp_month: String, x_card_code: String, x_first_name: String, x_last_name: String, x_address: String, x_city: String, x_state: String, x_zip: String, save_account: String, product_array: Map[String,Map[String,Any]], x_amount: String, products_json: String, auth_net_customer_profile_id: String,auth_net_payment_profile_id: String,customer_id: String)
```

But when I try to add one more variable to the controller and view like this:

```
Ok(views.html.payment(message,test,x_card_num,x_exp_date,exp_year,exp_month,x_card_code,x_first_name,x_last_name,x_address,x_city,x_state,x_zip,save_account,product_array,x_amount,products_json,auth_net_customer_profile_id,auth_net_payment_profile_id,customer_id,saved_payments_xml))


@(message: String, test: String, x_card_num: String, x_exp_date: String,exp_year: String, exp_month: String, x_card_code: String, x_first_name: String, x_last_name: String, x_address: String, x_city: String, x_state: String, x_zip: String, save_account: String, product_array: Map[String,Map[String,Any]], x_amount: String, products_json: String, auth_net_customer_profile_id: String,auth_net_payment_profile_id: String,customer_id: String, saved_payments_xml: String)
```

It gives me this error:

```
missing parameter type
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: is saved_payments_xml really a string?

Comment: yes saved_payments_xml is a string

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a limit to the number of parameters you can pass to a [template](https://github.com/playframework/Play20/blob/master/framework/src/templates/src/main/scala/ScalaTemplates.scala).  You've exceeded it when you add another parameter.

It's an undocumented and fairly arbitrary limit which is the result of how the code generation from a template works.  It is arguably a bug, but not one that I would fix since nobody needs this many parameters, and having this many makes code much less readable.

Your best resolution here is to refactor, for example by creating some case classes to represent Card and Address in your model, and pass those in instead.